# How to limit number of function evaluations in R

Tags: r, controls, mle

I am using optim() to do a ML estimation, and I'm wondering if there is a control option to limit the number of function evaluations? Otherwise it just keeps going and going.

My current code looks like this:

```
fit <- mle(LL, start = sv, method = "BFGS", control=list(maxit=10, reltol=1))
```

Thanks!

Comment: you have it there with the `maxit`

Comment: Thanks, but maxit only limits the number of iterations not the number of function evaluations. In my case, the program has been evaluating the objective function for several hundreds of times and it does not stop.

Answer (score 0):

You can add global counter variable and `stop()` or `browser()` call inside your `LL` function:

```
maxEvals<-0
LL<-function(...) {
    maxEvals<-maxEvals+1
    if (maxEvals>100)
       stop('Maximum evaluations reached')
}
```

But if even a single iteration of ML takes too long you probably should check your function and data.